# Types of thinking

Tags: cognitive-psychology, psychology

In general psychology, there are 3 types of thinking according to the way solving a problem: practical thinking, specifically visual thinking and theoretical thinking. Can you explain and give me some examples on these 3 types?
(I may have translated the terms not exactly)

Comment: Could you please provide a link to a source that states these 3 types of thinking?